# when i try to run open http://localhost, an error displays

Tags: html, asp.net, ms-access, isapi

when i try to run open http://localhost, this shows up **"An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click 'here' to find out more about this error."**

and when i click "here" it brings me to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

i don't understand why. here are my files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ipO8E8b64N5kjd4re-SLAHgj0NpPf-of?usp=sharing

Comment: Open up command window and type ipconfig command.  Look for IPv4 address under the Local Area Connection section.  This is your local IP address.  Then try using the IP  address instead of localhost.  Your local IP address will be of the form 192.168.nnn.nnn or 10.0.1.nnn for something similar.  You didn't say where you are attempting to "open http://localhost".  Is it from a program or a browser?

Comment: hi, thanks for the advice i was trying to open it from a browser, specifically google chrome.

Comment: using my ip address didnt work sadly, is there anything else i can do??